# unknown Invalid HTTP_HOST header in Django logs: api-keyboard.cmcm.com

Tags: django, http

I have been testing a new Django application on aws beanstalk. While looking through the httpd error logs I see thousands of lines like this:

> ... Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'api-keyboard.cmcm.com'. You may need to add 'api-keyboard.cmcm.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.*

Normally this is because I didn't add my own hostname to ALLOWED_HOSTS but this domain is completely foreign to me and I can't find references to it online.

So I'm wondering what this means, how do random host like this end up in the header, and if anyone recognized this one.

Thanks!

Comment: does this header appear on all views or on some specific view ?

Comment: @bhaskarc specific views that I don't implement, they look like they are intended for another application. example: api-keyboard.cmcm.com/freetheme/list?lang=en&vga=720x1436&count=10&offset=0&mcc=515&appv=506010

Comment: this is injecting ads and backlinks. If you are unaware of having done any such thing, this could be some kind of hack. Most likely your server credentials have been hacked to infect

Comment: @bhaskarc how is this intended to inject and ad or backlink?

Comment: I am no security guy... but if you open the above link you provided in browser its definitely trying to advertise apps. You may not necessarily be infected but atleast the guy is trying to do so and maybe failing because well it comes from a host that is not allowed in your settings. Plus the site cmcm.com is for  website called cheetahmobile and there are news articles that say they are trying to do nasty things. See for example: https://www.blackhatethicalhacking.com/cheetah-mobile-accused-committing-adfraud-several-apps/